# Using an object from main class in another class

Tags: java, object

So we are trying to create an AI robot and I found out that Java isn't that easy as I tought.
What I am trying to do is to get an object from another class.

Main class:

```
    package main;


   import lejos.hardware.Brick;
   import lejos.hardware.BrickFinder;
   import lejos.hardware.motor.EV3LargeRegulatedMotor;
   import lejos.robotics.RegulatedMotor;
   import movement.Forward;

   public final class Runner {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create brick
        Brick brick = BrickFinder.getDefault();

        // create motors
        RegulatedMotor left = new EV3LargeRegulatedMotor(brick.getPort("A"));
        RegulatedMotor right = new EV3LargeRegulatedMotor(brick.getPort("D"));

        //initialize motors
        left.setAcceleration(400);
        right.setAcceleration(400);

        left.setSpeed(400);
        right.setSpeed(400);



    Forward forward = new Forward();
        forward.moveForward();

    }



}
```

but the other class is this

```
    package movement;


   import lejos.utility.Delay;
   import main.Runner;

   public class Forward{

    public int speed;



    public void moveForward(){
        //moves forward for 5 seconds, then floats until motor stops and then closes the motors
            left.backward();
            right.backward();

            Delay.msDelay(5000);

            left.flt();
            right.flt();

            left.close();
            right.close();



    }

}
```

I would like to use the object left and right to make a method which would move forward.

Comment: Why Forward is a class? Doesn't moveForward makes more sense in Runner class?

Comment: @Averroes Well ... For such a small program, maybe. But did you ever hear about the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)? Let the `Forward` class implement some `Move` interface (or whatever) and assign instances of these moves to ... a mous click listener ... an automatic computer ... a whatever. Such classes make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Forward` class obviously needs a reference to the two motor instances. You should forward (no pun intended) them at construction time:

```
public class Forward {
    private final RegulatedMotor left;
    private final RegulatedMotor right;

    public Forward(RegulatedMotor left, RegulatedMotor right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public void moveForward() { ... }
}
```

Your `foward` metho now has access to them. Constructing such a `Forward` now must be done as following:

```
Forward forward = new Forward(left, right);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass left and right into Forward:

```
Forward forward = new Forward(left, right);
```

and change Forward constructor:

```
public class Forward{

    public int speed;
    RegulatedMotor left;
    RegulatedMotor right;

    public Forward(RegulatedMotor l, RegulatedMotor r) {
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!
Exactly what I was trying to achieve. As soon as I have a chance I'll post wether it is working or not. 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'd have to initialise them outside the "main" subroutine. And then you'd have to make them public and static.

```
public static RegulatedMotor left;
public static RegulatedMotor right;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    left = new EV3LargeRegulatedMotor(brick.getPort("A"));
    right = new EV3LargeRegulatedMotor(brick.getPort("D"));
    //rest of code as normal.
}
```

And then to access them from another class I believe you'd use:

```
Runner.left.Whateverfunction();
```

For the "left" object and;

```
Runner.right.Whateverfunction();
```

For the "right" object.

It's possible that I got a couple of syntax errors because I'm mainly a C# programmer, but I believe this should more or less be accurate.